# Does realm Javascript supports Join, Group By and Aggregation functions

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

To develop a React Native mobile app that shows statistics data, following functions to be used widely, does Realm will meet the needs?

Join
Group by
Aggregation
AutoIncrement

Kindly suggest any other ORM/DB that will be best fit for the statistical app?

Comment: Realm isn't a relational database, so while there is aggregation, there is no such thing as a join (there are links), and there is no such thing as groupBy (because you retrieve entire object, or more specifically a view to one). Autoincrement is technically "max+1" so it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative**

You can get date in `Realm Database` then by useign `js` **group by**

```
// Accepts the array and key
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  // Return the end result
  return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
    // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
    (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
      currentValue
    );
    // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
    return result;
  }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object
};

// Group by color as key to the person array
const personGroupedByColor = groupBy(person, 'color');
```